# Why is there wrong output after declare variable in loop? - (WrongQuestion: How to use Promises in a recursive method to declare a variable?)

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise

This question is based on this one:
[How do i add a summed list in a recursive method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52808151/how-do-i-add-a-summed-list-in-a-recursive-method)

This time I wanted to calculate the average of the `resultObject`. Therefore I created a `resultlist` with all `element.val` numbers in it and as soon as the `forEach` loop is over, the `tempuserlist` is iterated and the average is calculated.

This average object is then the new `result`. This example shows only a small example of my data set. For a larger data set there are problems with asynchronicity. I've tried Promises, but don't really know how to use them. Does anyone have an idea?

```
function somefunc(obj) {
   let temp = {};  
   let tempuserlist = [];
   for (var key in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         if(!obj[key].hasOwnProperty("userlist")) {
            somefunc(obj[key]);
         }
         obj[key].userlist.forEach(function(element) {
            if (!temp.hasOwnProperty(element.name)){
              tempuserlist.push(temp[element.user] = { user: element.user});
              temp[element.user].resultlist = [];
              temp[element.user].val= 0;
            } temp[element.name].resultlist.push(element.val);
         });
         for (const user in tempuserlist) {
              tempuserlist[user].val= Math.round(tempuserlist[user].val/ tempuserlist[user].resultlist.length);
         }
      }
   }
   obj.userlist = tempuserlist;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing asynchronous shown. Where do you call this function and where do you try to use the results?

Comment: "*For larger data there are problems with asynchrony.*" - what are you talking about? Please explicate.

Comment: After I executed the method I output the obj on the console... it looks like there are inconsistencies and the calculation of the avg is wrong on some levels... I also need to use AngularJS (a pretty old version -> I don't know if that's the reason)

Comment: @helloWorldJS Please provide a [mcve] where you include a sample input for a call that produces inconsistencies and wrong results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Okay folks,**

While I was preparing a small example I noticed my stupid mistake... the average should not be calculated in the loop... otherwise the average is calculated again and again... Sorry, it looks like my question doesn't have anything to do with promises and asynchronous programming after all. At least the result is now okay and I don't feel anything of asynchronous behavior yet ;)

I thank you anyway for the will to help me. Your suggestions have nevertheless helped me to look at things from a different point of view and not to get stuck on these promises.

```
function somefunc(obj) {
   let temp = {};  
      let tempuserlist = [];
      for (var key in obj) {
         if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if(!obj[key].hasOwnProperty("userlist")) {
               somefunc(obj[key]);
            }
            obj[key].userlist.forEach(function(element) {
               if (!temp.hasOwnProperty(element.name)){
                 tempuserlist.push(temp[element.user] = { user: element.user});
                 temp[element.user].resultlist = [];
                 temp[element.user].val= 0;
               } temp[element.name].resultlist.push(element.val);
            });
         }
      }
      for (const user in tempuserlist) {
        tempuserlist[user].val= Math.round(tempuserlist[user].val/ tempuserlist[user].resultlist.length);
      }
      obj.userlist = tempuserlist;
   }
```